# How to get this kind of data where rows in one table are columns in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

For example I had data in Table 'X' some thing like this,

```
ID   COLNAME   FROMATEID 
49    ENSURE        UF8
50    PROCESS       UF8
```

And now I had data in another table like,

```
FORMAT 1 2 3 4..49   50 
 UF8   NA....... YES  NO
```

In Table 'X'  We have multiple ID's for a format and those id's are column name in another table.. We have to get data like this:-

```
ACTIVITY   YES/NO
ENSURE       YES
PROCESS      NO
```

How can we achieve that?

Comment: DDL and sample data is important if we are to help you:  https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

The format of your tables is absurd.  The second table needs to be unpivoted . . . or you need a massive `case` expression.  For instance:

```
select x.colname as activity,
       (case when x.id = 1 then t2.[1]
             when x.id = 2 then t2.[2]
             . . .
             when x.id = 50 then t2.[50]
        end) as [Yes/No]
from x join
     table2 t2
     on x.formatid = t2.format ;
```